# Using Check boxes in Taggit

Tags: python, django, django-taggit

I am trying to use Taggit for users to be able to tag their posts while they are submitting a form. But I can successfully let them type manually(their tags), I am trying to change to check boxes. Any ideas?

```
    forms.py

    class TalesForm(ModelForm):

        class Meta:
            model = Tale
            fields = ('title', 'body', 'tags')
            m_tags = TagField()


    models.py

    class Tale(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
        body = models.TextField(max_length = 10000)
        pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.now)
        poster = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
        tags = TaggableManager()

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.title


    views.py

    def add(request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            if request.method=='POST':
                form=TalesForm(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                     m_tags = form.cleaned_data['tags']
                     newTale=Tale(title=form.cleaned_data['title'], body=form.cleaned_data['body'], poster = request.user)
                     newTale.save()
                     for m_tag in m_tags:
                        newTale.tags.add(m_tag)
                     #form.save_m2m()
                     return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/%s'%newTale.id)
                else:
                    return render_to_response('story/add.html', {'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))                                   
            else:
                form=TalesForm()
                args = {}
                args.update(csrf(request))
                args['form'] = form
                context= {'form': form}
                return render_to_response('story/add.html',context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/home')


html

<form method="post" action="/home/add/">
    {% csrf_token %}
   <div class="register_div">
        {% if form.title.errors %}<p class="error" >{{ form.title.errors }}</p>{% endif %}
        <p><label for="title"{% if form.title.errors %} class="error"{% endif %}>Title:</label></p>
        <p>{{ form.title}}</p>
 </div>
  <div class="register_div">
        {% if form.body.errors %}<p class="error" >{{ form.body.errors }}</p>{% endif %}
        <p><label for="body"{% if form.body.errors %} class="error"{% endif %}>Body:</label></p>
        <p>{{ form.body }}</p>
 </div>
  <div class="register_div">

        <p><label for="tag">Tags:</label></p>
        <p>{{ form.tags }}</p>
 </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Story" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

Define your form this way:

```
from taggit.models import Tag

class TalesForm(ModelForm):
    tags = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Tag.objects.all(),
                                          widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())

    class Meta:
        model = Tale
        fields = ('title', 'body', 'tags')
```